# ¿cómo puedo reemplazar parte de un correo electrónico?

Tags: java, regex, replace

Por ejemplo:

```
ejemplo@midominio.com
```

por

```
*****plo@midominio.com.
```

Solo se deben visualizar los últimos 3 caracteres antes de la arroba.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante revisar [ask] que te brinda información acerca de 

como formular preguntas en el sitio, agrega lo que has tratado o investigado. 

No olvides realizar el [tour]  del sitio, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eso lo puedes lograr de una manera muy sencilla entre tres funciones que son parte de la clase String.

- "**indexOf('posición de carácter a buscar')**"
- "**replaceAll('carácter o cadena a reemplazar o expresión
  regular','el nuevo valor')**"
- "**substring(posición inicial para extraer carácter o cadena,
  posición final)**"

Solución:

```
String correo = "ejemplo@stackoverflow.com";
String respuesta = correo.substring(0, correo.indexOf("@")-3).replaceAll("[a-z]", "*")//Texto que no importa reemplazado por "*"
+ correo.substring(correo.indexOf("@")-3,correo.length()); // El resto del correo
```

Salida:

```
 ****plo@stackoverflow.com
```

Explicación:

Básicamente lo único que hago es reemplazar los caracteres que no nos importan por "*" esto se logra con la parte de código

```
correo.substring(0, correo.indexOf("@")-3).replaceAll("[a-z]", "*")
```

Ordeno extraer la cadena desde la posición 0 hasta la posición donde se detecte "@" menos 3 posiciones, lo que nos permite obtener "ejem", eso se logro con la función "substring" y "indexOf", ahora reemplazamos esos caracteres por asteriscos con ayuda de la función "replaceAll" indicando mediante una expresión regular "[a-z]" que queremos sustituir cualquier letra del abecedario por un asterisco permitiéndonos reemplazar  "ejem" por "****".

Finalmente unimos el resto del correo con:

```
+correo.substring(correo.indexOf("@")-3,correo.length())
```

Extraemos con la función "substring" la cadena "plo@stackoverflow.com", lo que se indica es que se extraiga la cadena a partir de donde se detecte "@" menos 3 posiciones hasta el final de la cadena "correo.length".

Como puedes observar únicamente necesite de una linea de código para llegar a la solución, combinando varias funciones.
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo primero que se me ocurre es hacer un split tomando como caracter la @ y tomas todo el string que este antes de esta, posterior lo conviertes en un arreglo del tipo `char` y vas cambiando los caracteres que estén antes de `LONGITUD_DE_LA_CANDENA - 3`

```
String str = "ejemplo@midominio.com";
char[] strChars = str.toCharArray(); 
String palabra = str.split("@")[0];

for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length() - 3 ; i++ ) {
    strChars[i] = '*';
}
System.out.println(String.valueOf(strChars));
```